# How does this Cross Domain ajax request work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775295/jquery-grab-a-file-uploaded-with-input-type-file) question and in it is a link to http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/the-shortest-image-uploader-ever/ which has the following code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("image", file); // Append the file
fd.append("key", "6528448c258cff474ca9701c5bab6927");
// Get your own key: http://api.imgur.com/

// Create the XHR (Cross-Domain XHR FTW!!!)
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"); // Boooom!
xhr.onload = function() {
    // Big win!
    // The URL of the image is:
    JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
 }
 // Ok, I don't handle the errors. An exercice for the reader.
 // And now, we send the formdata
 xhr.send(fd);
```

How does this cross domain request work? I thought as a rule there are security restrictions that stop people from doing just this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is reponding with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to allow cross domain requests

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  
Cache-Control   max-age=604800
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  494
Content-Type    application/json
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea

[http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/)

Comment: is it still the case ?

Answer (score 1):

Imgur implements Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

> The CORS standard works by adding new HTTP headers that allow servers
>   to serve resources to permitted origin domains. Browsers support these
>   headers and enforce the restrictions they establish. Additionally, for
>   HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in
>   particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with
>   certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers
>   “preflight” the request, soliciting supported methods from the server
>   with an HTTP OPTIONS request header, and then, upon “approval” from
>   the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request
>   method. Servers can also notify clients whether “credentials”
>   (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with
>   requests.

See http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/ for more information.